# what does "fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])" doing?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

```
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    # Layer 1 - 28*28*1 to 14*14*32
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Layer 2 - 14*14*32 to 7*7*64
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
```

what does this `get.shape().as_list()[0]` do?

```
fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
```

Comment: Get the 0th element of the current shape of the `weights['wd1']`.

Comment: If you want some more details you could read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#shape) closely. It is a more involved topic.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding of `get.shape().as_list()`, here i am providing simple example, hope this help you.

```
import tensorflow as tf
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
Shape = c.get_shape().as_list()
print(Shape)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

It means`c` has `2 rows and 3 columns`.
When we print `Shape = c.get_shape().as_list()[0]` it return `0th` element of `c` in list format *(generally it return shape in tuple as (2,3))*

```
Shape = c.get_shape().as_list()[0]
```

Output:

```
2
```

When we use `tf.reshape` it returns a new tensor that has the same values as old tensor in the same order, except with a new shape specified by shape.

When we pass `shape of [-1]`, it flatten into 1D.

```
tf.reshape(c, [-1])
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.], dtype=float32)>
```

> fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])

To summarize, here we are flattening *(i.e into 1D)* weights of `conv2` layer *(i.e 2D)* and extracting `0th` element of `weights['wd1']`.